# If $K$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, $K$ has prime order, and $Z(G) = {1}$, then the Centralizer of $K$ in $G$ is equal to $K$

Tags: group-theory

Prove that if $K$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, $K$ has order $q$, where $q$ is prime, $G$ has order $pq$ where $p$ is a prime and less than $q$, and $Z(G) = {1}$, then the Centralizer of $K$ in $G$ is equal to $K$.

It is clear that either the order of the Centralizer is $q$ or $pq$, but I don't know how to show that the order can not be equal to $pq$. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

$$\left|C_G(K)\right|=pq\implies C_G(K)=G\implies K\subset Z(G)$$

and this last is impossible since it's given $\;|Z(G)|=1\;$ .